# Angular Universal http server side rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal, universal-cli

I am using universal-cli and I try to make SEO friendly site but have problem with http request it just not rendering, here is live example:

http://pushsc.com/show/code/58bc83760a58d602a0b99d14

I just get static elements but not those which come from http...

Is it normal behaviour for Universal?